# VMWare Server VM Network Utilization

Tags: networking, vmware-server, vps, bandwidth, snmp

I run multiple blogs atop VMWare Server.  I have been looking for a good way to monitor the bandwidth each of these blogs uses.

I would especially like a tool that allows me to count the bandwidth from the first of each month, and the current network utilization.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can highly recommend [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/). That's what I use to monitor bandwidth usage in my virtual machines.

Comment: I will try this out tonight, and I'm hoping it is as easy as the screens look.

Comment: It's a little bit tricky to set up, but it's well worth it! To get a jump start you might want to look for a cacti "Virtual Appliance", a VMware machine with cacti preinstalled

Comment: Cacti is the way to go. Remember that your blogs doesnt have anything to do with vmware, you want to monitor your virtual servers the same way you would monitor a physical server.

Comment: Cacti seems to solve my problems plus have some extra fun built in.  Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome. I've been using it for years and love it!

Answer (score 0):

vCenter Server monitors VMWare Server 2.0 hosts and automatically keeps daily, weekly, monthly and the last year's statistics in a MS SQL Server database.

It's not free though.